# Create a new categorical variable in Stata using 3 variables in the current dataset

Tags: stata

I need some help with creating a new variable. I feel like the `egen` function is what I need to use but I can't figure it out.

I have 3 variables for cancer treatment - radiotherapy, chemotherapy and surgery - given with the number of times each patient has received each treatment.

I would like to create a new "Treatment" variable where 1 = radiotherapy, 2 = chemotherapy, 3 = surgery, 4 = combination (with 1 or more for any of the above 3), 5 = none

Answer (score 0):

You should always show code you have tried and give example data. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance.

Assume variables `radio` `chemo` `surgery` with values 0 or positive.

```
gen treatment = 5 
replace treatment = 1 if radio & !chemo & !surgery 
replace treatment = 2 if chemo & !radio & !surgery 
replace treatment = 3 if surgery & !chemo & !radio 
replace treatment - 4 if ((surgery > 0) + (radio > 0) + (chemo > 0)) > 1
```

using the facts that non-zero is true and its negation is false. See [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/)

Another way to do it:

```
gen treatment = 5 
replace treatment = 1 if radio 
replace treatment = cond(treatment == 1, 4, 2) if chemo 
replace treatment = cond(inlist(treatment, 1, 2), 4, 3) if surgery
```

In similar circumstances I would code your none category 0, not 5. That's likely to yield more sensible graphs and tables.

Code not tested.